# Trouble Installing Windows using Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp

Using Bootcamp to install a Windows partition on my iMac. I've created a partition on the HD. The format Bootcamp defaulted to is "Mac Extended OS (Journaled)." But when I try to install Windows on that partition from a USB external drive I created for this task (i.e., it has Windows installed on it), the error message I get is that the program can't be installed unless the partition is in NTFS format. How do I reformat just that partition to NTFS. . .or is that not possible? Thanks.

Comment: When you get this error message, is not there a button labeled Format?

Comment: I would be more concerned that you are trying to install Windows on a partition that is "Mac Extended OS (Journaled)"  formatted. The partition created by the Boot Camp Assistant application would **not** be formatted this way. I suspect you have made a mistake.

Comment: Is the USB drive bootable? If not, that could be your problem.